# twitter bootstrap typeahead cache json result

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap lib in my application and is being a great experience. Now i'm implementing bootstrap typeahad for autocomplete.
Here I am having a problem with caching the results to avoid many requests to the server. while doing research on the web I found this lib https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js also called twitter typeahead. It seems that is very different from the one on boottrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead. Am I wrong?

The first option seems to be the most suitable for the intended but I have the following questions:

- How do I use prefetch? This has to be a pre-existing json file or may be a first request to the server on pageload?

  Is there any working example that use the prefetch and the remote?

Just for reference : this is my actual code with twitter boottrap typeahead ( not twitter typeahead )

```
$searchbox.typeahead(
      {
          minLength: 2,
          source: function (query, process) {
              $SearchID.val('');
              persons = [];
              map = {};
              $.getJSON("App_Services/MyService.svc/GetData", { max: 100, criteria: query }, function (data) {
 
                  $.each(data, function (i, person) {
                      map[person.name] = person;

                      persons.push(person.name);
                  });
                  process(persons);
              });

          },
          updater: function (item) {
              selected = map[item].id;
              //alert(selected)
              return item;
          },
          matcher: function (item) {
              if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                  return true;
              }
          },
          sorter: function (items) {
              return items.sort();
          },
          highlighter: function (item) {
              var regex = new RegExp('(' + this.query + ')', 'gi');
              return '<div>' + item.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>") + '</div>';
          }
      })
```

Just to clarify. What I am trying to do is create a cache of the results and use only the server if no match is found in the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.query_cache = {};
$searchbox.typeahead({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(query, process) {
        if (query_cache[query]) {
            process(query_cache[query]); //If cached, use it !
            return;
        }
        $SearchID.val('');
        persons = [];
        map = {};
        $.getJSON("App_Services/MyService.svc/GetData", {
            max: 100,
            criteria: query
        }, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, person) {
                map[person.name] = person;
                persons.push(person.name);
            });
            query_cache[query] = persons; //Add it if it doesn't exist.
            process(persons);
        });
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        selected = map[item].id;
        //alert(selected)
        return item;
    },
    matcher: function(item) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    sorter: function(items) {
        return items.sort();
    },
    highlighter: function(item) {
        var regex = new RegExp('(' + this.query + ')', 'gi');
        return '<div>' + item.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>") + '</div>';
    }
})
```

What this code does ?

1. It defines a global variable `query_cache`;
2. Then it looks for cached results. And if present, it will process that, so no load on server.
3. If it is not cached, it caches it, so next time, it can be used.
4. Solves your problem.

Comment: This looks great for the basic bootstrap typeahead. i'm using this one (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) because it have more advance options. Now it works great . Thanks for your feedback. This is a great code snippet :)

Comment: Hi @Sandcar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the green check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid many requests to the server in your case, you should add cache in http header when you output the json on server side.

in PHP it likes:

```
$time = time();  
$interval = 3600 * 24 * 60; //cache for 60 days  
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('r',$time));  
header('Expires: '.gmdate('r',($time+$interval)));  
header('Cache-Control: max-age='.$interval);  
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit;
```

to avoid many query to the database, you should cache the frequently query result by using something like memcache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is an application in C #. I'm not very familiar with php. I am looking for a solution at the typeahead code level.